# How do I find the pixel color of a given point inside a JPanel with a moving image?

Tags: swing, graphics, bufferedimage

How do I find the pixel color of a given point inside a JPanel with a moving image? Can I do this using BufferedImage or Graphics?

Answer (score 0):

You would take whatever frame you are trying to get the pixel color from and then turn it into a BufferedImage and then use .getRGB(x,y) which will return an integer pixel. Turn that into a Color Object and then use getRed() getBlue() getGreen() getAlpha() for the values.

Comment: How do you find multiple frames on a JPanel since my Image is moving?